# TYPO3 - How to display a div in all languages except one?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to display a div in all languages except fr. If the current language of the page fr, then don't (render) this div. Is it possible with ViewHelpers in my Fluid Template? And what is the best solution for it?

```
<div>EN, FI, DE... (Not FR)</div>
```

I expect the div to be displayed in all languages except fr.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the language as a variable through TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_myext.settings.language = en
[globalVar = GP:L=1]
  plugin.tx_myext.settings.language = fr
[globalVar = GP:L=2]
  plugin.tx_myext.settings.language = nl
[global]
```

And in your Fluid template:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.language} == 'fr'>
  <f:else>
    <div>Not visible for French</div>
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

If this is a page template, not an extension template, you can do basically the same, but your TypoScript would be something like:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  # Page Main template
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    settings { 
      language = en
    }
  }
}
[globalVar = GP:L=1]
  page.10.settings.language = fr
[globalVar = GP:L=2]
  page.10.settings.language = nl
[global]
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond! I did it as followed :)
<f:if condition="{v:page.language()} !== 2">
     <f:then>
         <div>EN, FI, DE... (Not FR)</div>
      </f:then>
</f:if>
2 is fr

Comment: just for clarification, there is no need to use variables for page templates as implied by the answer above - you can just as well use settings in page templates (which I'd suggest to use over variables in this particular case, since  they are static values and there is no need for the extra CObject rendering overhead that variables bring along). It would be `page.10.settings.xxx` in that case. But I'd probably do it differently and use a custom viewHelper that evaluates the language aspect (if you happen to use TYPO3 v9) which is more accurate, especially when you use language fallbacks etc.

Comment: @FranzKoch You're right. I've edited my answer to change variables to settings.